# Exporting NetLogo data to graph with nodes and edges

Tags: netlogo, gephi

I have created some links between agents (turtles) in NetLogo. This links will change at each time step. My aim is to export this data (i.e., turtles and links b/w them) to graph with vertices (turtles) edges (links), which can be given as input to Gephi. Is it possible to see the changes which occurs in netlogo in the graph when it is linked with Gephi. Can someone help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To export your network data in a format usable by Gephi, I would suggest using the [`nw:save-graphml`](https://github.com/NetLogo/NW-Extension#save-graphml) primitive from NetLogo's [NW Extension](https://github.com/NetLogo/NW-Extension#readme). This will give produce a file in the [GraphML file format](http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/), which Gephi can read.

I guess you *could* re-save your network at each time step and overwrite your file, but I'm not sure if Gephi can display your changes dynamically. And depending on the size of your network, it might be slow.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to use Gephi to see how the network changes over time, in a changing network that is generated by NetLogo?  That's what @NicolasPayette's answer suggests, so I'll make the same assumption.

Gephi can display "dynamic graphs", i.e. networks that change over time.  My understanding is that are two file formats that allow Gephi to import dynamic graphs: [GEXF](http://gexf.net/format/), and a special CSV (comma-separated) format that Gephi calls ["Spreadsheet"](https://gephi.github.io/users/supported-graph-formats/spreadsheet/).  Nicolas mentioned GraphML, which is a very nice network data format, but it doesn't handle dynamic graphs.  And as far as I know, NetLogo doesn't generate GEXF or Gephi's "Spreadsheet" format.

However, the Gephi Spreadsheet format is very simple, and it would not be difficult to write a NetLogo procedure that would write a file in that format.  This procedure would write new rows to the "Spreadsheet" CSV file on each NetLogo tick.  Then Gephi could read in the file, and you'd be able to move back and forth in time, seeing how the graph changes.  (You might need to use a bit of trial and error to figure out how to write Spreadsheet files based on the [description](https://gephi.github.io/users/supported-graph-formats/spreadsheet/) on the Gephi site.)

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to display the evolving graph online using the graphstream protocol. Plugins for [NetLogo](https://github.com/graphstream/gs-netlogo/wiki) as well as for [gephi](https://marketplace.gephi.org/plugin/graph-streaming/) provide support for this.